# Coded ui playback via labs (kicked off from MTM), how do you set the screen resolution of the active desktop session?

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I've setup labs in such a way that the agent account automatically logs in, this means I no longer need an rdc session. The problem is that the screen resolution is 800x600 during playback.

How can I adjust this to a more realistic resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is : You can't.

Coded ui tests are designed to run in "console mode", they take the native desktop resolution of the machine in "console mode" - unless there is an active RDP session open that corresponds to the "Run interactively" user account, in this case it runs on that RDP session at the resolution of the session.

So to be totally automated you would need to create Agents and set their resolution individually.